# Are there "All" and "Any" functions in Mathematica?

Tags: functions, boolean-computation

In Python, there is a function `all` which returns true if all of its arguments are true, and `any` which returns true if at least one of its arguments is true. I find these quite useful in functional programming. Given how much Mathematica encourages functional programming constructs, I was surprised not to find anything equivalent to these `all` and `any` functions in the documentation. Does Mathematica have equivalents to these functions, or some standard way to achieve the same effect?

I can implement them myself as

```
AllOf[b_List] := Fold[And, True, b][[1]]
AllOf[b__] := Fold[And, True, {b}][[1]]

AnyOf[b_List] := Fold[Or, True, b][[1]]
AnyOf[b__] := Fold[Or, True, {b}][[1]]
```

(these may not be always correct, but they've worked for my purposes). But I would rather use something built-in if it exists.

Comment: Alternatively, `AllOf[b_List] := And @@ b` and `AnyOf[b_List] := Or @@ b` ...

Comment: This question was asked before on SO several times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181470/custom-function-with-non-standard-evaluation-behaves-like-table, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911827/non-standard-evaluation-and-packedarray, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867076/how-should-i-write-a-function-to-be-used-in-apply-in-mathematica/4867297#4867297. In my answers there, I also discuss the short-circuiting.

Comment: Note, for more general forms (if the problem involves values other than True/False) you would probably want to use `MemberQ` and `FreeQ`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Both, `And` and `Or` should work for `All` and `Any` respectively. You may have to get creative in how you apply them, though. For instance,

```
And @@ {True, False, True}
```

works just like you would expect

```
AllOf @ {True, False, True}
```

to without any additional work. Similarly,

```
Or @@ {False, True, False}
```

works like `AnyOf`.

Comment: Huh, somehow I missed that `And` and `Or` can apply to multiple (>2) arguments.

Comment: It's interesting to mention that they are also short circuiting and have `HoldAll`.  So `False && expr` will never evaluate `expr`.

Comment: @Szabolcs See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911827/non-standard-evaluation-and-packedarray, for a short-circuiting implementation. I also discuss short-curcuiting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867076/how-should-i-write-a-function-to-be-used-in-apply-in-mathematica/4867297#4867297

Comment: If you want to benefit from short circuiting, while applying `And` to a `List` like in this answer, note that you have to use `Unevaluated`, i.e. `Apply[And, Unevaluated[{False, expr}]]`

Answer (score 26):

You can implement equivalents of the `any` and `all` functions in MATLAB and python in Mathematica using the [`MemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MemberQ.html) and [`FreeQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FreeQ.html) functions as:

```
any[x_List] := MemberQ[x, True]
all[x_List] := FreeQ[x, False]
```

For large lists, these will be about an order of magnitude faster in the worst case to several orders faster in the best case, when compared to the `And` and `Or` solutions.

Comment: +1. I suspect that the speed advantage comes largely from the fact that in your functions, the clauses have been already evaluated, while `And` and `Or` evaluate them only if necessary. If you add the time it took to evaluate those, the difference might be not as large. OTOH, if, for a particular problem,  you have some fast vectorized way to obtain the list of True/False, this may indeed be much faster than using `And` / `Or`.

Comment: This is really "lateral thinking" :). I always use `MemberQ` and `FreeQ` the other way around (ie using the "element" as the free var)

Answer (score 17):

The Wolfram Language and *Mathematica* 10 (available now on the Raspberry Pi) have new functions — [`AnyTrue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnyTrue.html), [`AllTrue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AllTrue.html), [`NoneTrue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NoneTrue.html) — which take a predicate and test any/all/none on the input list. For example:

```
AnyTrue[Range@5, EvenQ]
(* True *)

AllTrue[{True, False, False}, TrueQ] (* or Identity in place of TrueQ *)
(* False *)
```

These functions can also be turned into a predicate themselves by using just a test function as a single argument:

```
NoneTrue[StringQ]@{"a", 1, 23}
(* False *)
```

Comment: The latter one could use `Identity` in place of `TrueQ`, provided all elements are `True` or `False`.  The `AllTrue[EvenQ][{2, 4, 6}]` syntax is interesting to show too.

Comment: Yes, I'll add that syntax in as well.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the simple form where you already have a list of True|False elements, you may want lazy evaluation in creating that list, short circuiting if the test fails.  You can do this with `Hold`.  I include a `Print` statement so that you can see what actually evaluates:

```
(Print@#; # != 0) & /@ Hold[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
And @@ %
```

---

```
(Print@#; # != 0) & /@ Hold[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
Or @@ %
```

---

Another form that can come in handy if you have a function that uses two arguments is `Inner`:

```
a = {91, 95, 72, 90, 82, 97, 76, 81, 82, 70};
b = {7, 4, 3, 9, 1, 4, 5, 6, 5, 2};

Inner[(Print[##]; Divisible[##]) &, a, b, And]

Inner[(Print[##]; Divisible[##]) &, a, b, Or]
```

Answer (score 12):

Another way for `All` is to use [VectorQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VectorQ.html?q=VectorQ&lang=en) function

```
VectorQ[lis, TrueQ]
```

Answer (score 1):

No one gives a summary of explicit timing. Here is one

First, define

```
ClearAll[timing]
timing[a_] := {
   Prepend[And @@ a; // RepeatedTiming, "And@@a"],
   Prepend[FreeQ[a, False]; // RepeatedTiming, "FreeQ[a,False]"], 
   Prepend[MemberQ[a, False]; // RepeatedTiming, "MemberQ[a,False]"], 
   Prepend[VectorQ[a, TrueQ]; // RepeatedTiming, "VectorQ[a,TrueQ]"], 
   Prepend[AllTrue[a, TrueQ]; // RepeatedTiming, "AllTrue[a,TrueQ]"], 
   Prepend[AnyTrue[a, TrueQ]; // RepeatedTiming, 
    "AnyTrue[a,TrueQ]"]} // TableForm
```

**Even random True and False mixed List**

```
a = RandomChoice[{True, False}, 10^6];
timing[a]
```

gives

```
7.05217*10^-6   Null    And@@a
3.86491*10^-7   Null    FreeQ[a,False]
3.76835*10^-7   Null    MemberQ[a,False]
2.95758*10^-7   Null    VectorQ[a,TrueQ]
2.88454*10^-7   Null    AllTrue[a,TrueQ]
3.70405*10^-7   Null    AnyTrue[a,TrueQ]
```

**All True List**

```
a = RandomChoice[{True}, 10^6];
timing[a]
```

gives

```
0.0139276   Null    And@@a
3.06406*10^-7   Null    FreeQ[a,False]
3.06094*10^-7   Null    MemberQ[a,False]
0.0774998   Null    VectorQ[a,TrueQ]
0.0791204   Null    AllTrue[a,TrueQ]
2.84386*10^-7   Null    AnyTrue[a,TrueQ]
```

**All False List**

```
a = RandomChoice[{False}, 10^6];
timing[a]
```

gives

```
0.0085237   Null    And@@a
4.08738*10^-7   Null    FreeQ[a,False]
4.20621*10^-7   Null    MemberQ[a,False]
3.25424*10^-7   Null    VectorQ[a,TrueQ]
3.15501*10^-7   Null    AllTrue[a,TrueQ]
0.0902116   Null    AnyTrue[a,TrueQ]
```

It seems `FreeQ` and `MemberQ` are best

But `VectorQ` is good for packed array

```
s = ConstantArray[1, 1000000];
FreeQ[IntegerQ /@ s, True]; // RepeatedTiming
VectorQ[s, IntegerQ]; // RepeatedTiming
s = Developer`FromPackedArray@ConstantArray[1, 1000000];
FreeQ[IntegerQ /@ s, True]; // RepeatedTiming
VectorQ[s, IntegerQ]; // RepeatedTiming
```

gives

```
{0.111584, Null}
{1.91957*10^-7, Null}
{0.107412, Null}
{0.00319087, Null}
```