# How are MemberQ and FreeQ so fast?

Tags: performance-tuning, implementation-details

I would like to understand the implementation that allows `MemberQ` and `FreeQ` to be as fast as they are.

I noticed this thanks to [this fine answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/922/121).

I start with a list of True|False values:

```
lst = Insert[Table[True, {500000}], False, 499000];
```

It is not packed:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[lst]
```

> False

I compare timings:

```
Scan[Identity, lst] ~Do~ {100} // Timing
MemberQ[lst, False] ~Do~ {100} // Timing
FreeQ[lst, False]   ~Do~ {100} // Timing
```

> {4.93, Null}
>
> {0.405, Null}
>
> {0.25, Null}

What allows these functions to be more than an order of magnitude faster than simply Scanning the list?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you observed seems to be an instance of the general behavior of the pattern-matcher when used with what I call "syntactic patterns" - patterns which only reflect the rigid structure of an expression, like e.g. `_f`. The speed-up with respect to the scanning is because the main evaluation loop is avoided - for `FreeQ` and `MemberQ`, the scannng is done all inside the pattern-matcher, which is lower-level compared to the main evaluator.

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-can-i-ensure-that-i-am-constructing-patterns-in-the-most-efficient-way-possi/295#295), and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786389/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-check-that-a-list-is-a-list-of-numbers-in-argumen/8787304#8787304), there are some examples of this behavior, and further discussion. I think that a good rule of thumb is that you gain an order and a half of magnitude speed-up by clever use of syntactic patterns in place of top-level scanning code (pushing all work into the pattern-matcher), and you gain 2-3 orders of magnitude speed-up if you manage to recast the problem as a vectorized numerical problem on packed arrays.

Comment: Would you add some examples to this, please?

Comment: @Spartacus I added links to two relevant questions / answers, containing some examples - will this satisfy you? I am afraid that otherwise  right now I'd have to just copy those example and paste here, which doesn't make much sense IMO.

Comment: @Spartacus Most functions that do their job "in one go" (`Union`, `Split`, etc.) seems to be fast too.

Comment: @Szabolcs they are only fast with default comparison etc. functions, and that is also because they bypass the main evaluator with default functions (not to mention that `Union` switched to a pairwise comparisons for explicit comparison function, which leads to a quadratic-time algorithm, so `Union`, as well as `DeleteDuplicates`, are bad examples here. `Sort` and `Split` are good examples). This is probably what you meant by "in one go" - they don't have to oscillate between the kernel code and high-level evaluations. It is these oscillations that kill the performance.

Comment: @Leonid, it is good. Szabolcs yes I suppose so. I guess I saw FreeQ / MemberQ (in the basic form) as more general than e.g. DeleteDuplicates (also in the basic form). Perhaps that was a mistake. I would not have posted this question except that it seemed like a slow day, but I did not honestly know the answer beforehand.

Comment: Dear @LeonidShifrin, do patterns with `Head` specification (as in `x_Head`) count as what you call "syntactic patterns"?  I would have thought that checking for matched head is just like conditionals... (*i.e.* Does `x` have the right `Head`?)

Comment: also @LeonidShifrin, do I pay a speed-penalty if I use `Alternatives` compared with `Condition`?

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes, `_head` is a good example of `syntactic` pattern. As to `Alternatives`, it is still syntactic pattern (as far as the alternative patterns are all syntactic), since it only involves pattern-matcher and not evaluator.