# What's wrong with this pattern of the form Except[Repeated[....]]?

Tags: pattern-matching, function-construction

I'm trying to build a head that recognizes molecules. Here's the code

```
Mol::arg = "Invalid molecule.";
Mol[Except[Subscript[_String, _Integer] ..]] := Message[Mol::arg]
```

I'd expect that this code should recognize molecules of the form

```
Mol[Subscript["C", 4], Subscript["N", 5]]
```

but it should issue the message if something like

```
Mol[Subscript["C", 4], 7]
```

is entered. However, when I enter this last one, no message is issued. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To simplify the example, consider this:

```
f[Except[1 ..]] := "match"

{f[1], f[3], f[3, 5]}
```

> ```
> {f[1], "match", f[3, 5]}
> ```

`Except` is a single argument, not a sequence.  Therefore the definition cannot match when there are multiples arguments of `f`.

---

I think Rojo's answer is the cleanest method to get the behavior you want, but another is:

```
mol::arg = "Invalid molecule.";
pat = Subscript[_String, _Integer]

mol[x__] := With[{}, Message[mol::arg] /; ! MatchQ[{x}, {pat ..}]]
```

Or, using a trick Rojo showed me to prevent infinite recursion:

```
Module[{guard = True},
  x : mol[pat ..] /; guard := Block[{guard = False}, x];
      mol[__]     /; guard := Message[mol::arg]
]
```

Comment: @Rojo As you say, I just need a wrapper, so that when I pattern match something like `_Mol`, I can be sure that it is formatted in the correct way.

Comment: "`Except` is a single argument, not a sequence." ... So that explains why my code doesn't work. But then, is there some sort of `SequenceExcept` in Mathematica?

Comment: @becko not that I am aware of.  I added a couple more method you could use to my answer.  As it stands, my post is the only one that actually answers the question you asked, therefore IMHO you should either Accept it, or (as it seems you prefer) change your answer to move emphasis from *why* to *how*.

Comment: I thought of this, but at the time you were about the only one other than me that found it cool, so I got depressed, you know. Now you made me happy using it. My bet it that it's the fastest of all, but can't test right now, only in about half an hour. Let me know if you test first ;D

Comment: I accepted @Rojo answer before because, as you say, it's the neatest solution to the *how* question. But you're right that your answer is the only one that truly fits my question.

Comment: @Rojo I can't test the speed right now either, but will do it soon and post here.

Comment: @Rojo initial testing indicates `Mol[___, Except[Subscript[_String, _Integer]], ___]` is still several times faster, probably [for this reason.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1420/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In [the answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1420/121) you reference, Leonid says "(...) an instance of the general behavior of the pattern-matcher when used with what I call *syntactic patterns* - patterns which only reflect the rigid structure of an expression, like e.g. `_f`." I don't think `___, Except[Subscript[_String, _Integer]], ___` qualifies as a *syntactic pattern*.

Comment: In a very uninformed and merely intuitive guess, I'd say that Heike's `p__ /; MatchQ[{p}, Except[{Subscript[_String, _Integer] ..}]]` is easier to match than @Rojo `___, Except[Subscript[_String, _Integer]], ___`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I followed some of the links in the answer you referenced. Leonid says that `MatchQ` slows pattern matching, but so does double blanks `__` ...

Comment: @becko you're right, I misapplied Leonid's answer.  What I mean is that both of the methods in my answer involve upper-level programming while Rojo's answer is pure pattern matching, even if it does use `___`, and perhaps that is why it's faster.  I am now well aware that [*Mathematica's* pattern engine has performance issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522876/mathematicas-pattern-matching-poorly-optimized), and I certainly don't mean to imply that pattern matching *will* be faster than top level programming.

Answer (score 13):

I'd suggest

```
Mol[___, Except[Subscript[_String, _Integer]], ___]
```

I think it's an interesting question. I never dug into this but as far as I recall, I never saw `Except` working for pattern sequences

Comment: This also works. But I think it's slower than Heike's method. Just run ...

Comment: `molecule=Sequence@@Table[Subscript[RandomChoice[{"C","N","S","H"}],RandomInteger[{1,500}]],{i,1,1000}]`

Comment: and then this ...

Comment: `{Timing[Mol1[molecule];], Timing[Mol2[molecule];]}`

Comment: where Mol1 is defined with Heike's method and Mol2 is defined with your method. I get `{{0., Null}, {0.015, Null}}`.

Comment: @Becko, I get better timings for my version. Averaging 0.000146606 in Heike's and 0.0000437927 in mine, for your example

Answer (score 9):

You could do something like this

```
Clear[Mol];
Mol::arg = "Invalid molecule.";
Mol[p__ /; MatchQ[{p}, Except[{Subscript[_String, _Integer] ..}]]] :=  Message[Mol::arg]
```

Comment: cool. That works just like I wanted it. But what's wrong my code? And also, isn't the `/;` a little inefficient compared to other forms of pattern matching? (Not that I care for this particular application about efficiency)