# Why Infinity /. _?(# < 6 &) -> 0 replaces Infinity with ComplexInfinity?

Tags: replacement

Suppose I define a matrix:

```
mat = {
    {Infinity, 4, 9},
    {6, Infinity, 10},
    {8, 9, Infinity}
   };
```

Now I want to replace all values smaller than `6` with `0`,

```
mat /. _?(# < 6 &) -> 0
```

However, that ends up replacing `Infinity` with `ComplexInfinity`, which is undesired. Why is this happening?

**Update:** A simpler example, as suggested by kguler in the comments, is:

```
Infinity /. _?(# < 6 &) -> 0
```

which returns `ComplexInfinity`.

Comment: see the output of `Infinity /. _?(# < 6 &) -> 0 // Trace`.

Comment: You can get what you want using: `mat /. _?(# < 6 &) -> 0 /. ComplexInfinity -> Infinity`

Comment: Why the close votes? I think this wasn't *that* obvious! I changed the title using @kguler's (+1) simpler example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A few things are happening in there.

First, `Infinity` is being replaced by `DirectedInfinity[1]` in order to perform the comparison. In fact `Infinity` is just an abbreviation of `DirectedInfinity[1]`. You can see it by doing:

```
Infinity // FullForm
(* DirectedInfinity[1] *)
```

Next, the comparison takes place. It's done in the same way Mathematica always does, like in:

```
h[1] /. _?(# < 6 &) -> 0
(* h[0] *)
```

But in your case the head `h` is `DirectedInfinity`. So your result is

```
(* DirectedInfinity[0] *)
```

Now, that is a non-oriented infinity, exactly the same as `ComplexInfinity`. Just try it:

```
DirectedInfinity[0]
(* ComplexInfinity *)
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 7):

At some point, someone might want to write a good question about how to debug patterns that do not work as (naively) expected.  When I was first learning about patterns, I found it frustrating and confusing.  Now, I wonder what was the big deal.  It can still be difficult to find the right pattern, just as there are difficult problems in every area.  The gap in my understanding between then and now suggests there are things to be learned and things that could be explained.  However, my understanding has not advanced to the point that I have a systematic and foolproof method of what to do when a pattern does not match what you intended.  I can share one or two pretty good principles, but beyond that, it's like a lot of problem solving, I stab this way or that until I realize how stupid I've been or I have one of those rare moments we've all had when something rather clever actually occurs to us.

#### Two pretty good principles:

1. **Examine the `FullForm`.**  A pattern, when it matches, matches an expression in its full form. As has been pointed out `FullForm[Infinity]` shows `DirectedInfinity[1]`.  There are three expressions that might possibly match any pattern, the whole expression, the head `DirectedInfinity`, and the argument `1`.
2. **Isolate the problem.**  Full forms are hard to read.  The smaller you can make an expression that exhibits the problem, the better.  As has been pointed out, the problem in the present question is with `Infinity` and not with the entire matrix.

#### Some tools

There are some things you can do to understand what a pattern is matching.  Other users may use other methods, quite possibly better ones.

**`Position`** can show which parts of an expression matches a pattern.

```
mat // FullForm
Position[mat, _?(# < 6 &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**`Cases`** will extract expressions that match.  The result might or might not be enlightening.

```
Cases[mat, _?(# < 6 &), Infinity]
(*  {1, 4, 1, 1}  *)
```

One problem with `Cases` is that the returned values are evaluated (see below for further consideration of evaluation).  Mr.Wizard has written a function [**`heldCases`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31754/121) that will return the matches inside `HoldComplete`.  The syntax is like `Cases`:

```
heldCases[mat, _?(# < 6 &), Infinity]
(*  HoldComplete[1, 4, 1, 1]  *)
```

**`Print`** can print useful information sometimes.  The following shows that the `1` matches

```
Infinity // FullForm
Infinity /. _?((Print[{FullForm@#, # < 6}]; # < 6) &) -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Evaluation** can be triggered by replacement.  For instance, in the present case, `DirectedInfinity[0]` evaluates to `DirectedInfinity[]`.  This is potentially confusing, since in the resulting output, it does not appear that something was replaced by `0` as specified by the rule.  Controlling evaluation so that some things happen and others do not is another area of *Mathematica* that has been difficult for me.  In the present case we can use **`Hold`**.  I write `Hold @@ {mat}` so that `mat` will evaluate and then be held.  The replacements will happen, but the results are not evaluated.

```
mat // FullForm
Hold @@ {mat} /. match_?(# < 6 &) -> 0 // FullForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Highlighting.** I hardly ever do this, but tracking down the parts returned by `Position` can be tedious.  The use of `HoldForm` may be overly cautious on my part.

```
Position[heldexpr = HoldForm @@ {mat}, _?(# < 6 &)]
ReplacePart[heldexpr, # -> Style[Extract[heldexpr, #, HoldForm], Red] & /@ %]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way to show where the matches are is to use the positions to extract the parent expression of the expression that matches.  This can be more useful than the use of `Cases` above:

```
Position[heldexpr = HoldForm @@ {mat}, _?(# < 6 &)]
Extract[heldexpr, Most /@ %, HoldForm@*FullForm]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note from the position information, it is the second element of `List[DirectedInfinity[1], 4, 9]` that matches the pattern.

---

Well that is more than enough for the present case.  Perhaps some of the techniques will be helpful to others who are struggling to learn how pattern matching works.

Comment: WReach's [traceView4](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29340) can be helpful, too.  One might want to replace the `e` in the bodies of the two definitions of `substep` by `FullForm /@ e`.  Also related: [334](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334); adapted from Mr.Wizard's comment: `TraceScan[Print[TraceLevel[], " : ", FullForm /@ #] &, Infinity /. _?(# < 6 &) -> 0]`.

Comment: Great summary answer.  I [regularly recommend `FullForm`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A121+[pattern-matching]+FullForm) for understanding pattern matching you went well beyond that.  FWIW I think my [`heldCases`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31754/121) is useful for debugging patterns as the matched items are not inadvertently evaluated.  If you agree would you mind including mention of it?

Comment: This is a very good answer. However, you might want to post a separate question and answer it yourself, since that will make this information easier to find for others. If you do, please post a link in a comment to my question.

Comment: I agree with becko.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Thanks.  Yes, I'll include `heldCases`.  I missed or did not remember that one.

Comment: @becko and Mr.Wizard.  It would be nice for a general question to have two or three good examples for potential answerers to deal with (imo).  I'd appreciate any suggestions.  Nothing too complicated, but with three, there might be a range of issues exhibited.

Comment: If it is worth it, feel free to use/link the example in this question.

Comment: @becko I intended to. :)

Comment: Maybe http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5822/534