Handling infinite quantities in list plots
I have two large arrays of values say {{x,y,z1}..} and {{x,y,z2}..} and I would like to plot the following array of data {{x,y,z1/z2}..} in a ListContourPlot function.
The problem I am facing is that there are significant regions in {x,y} where z2 is zero and I get Infinite expression 1/0 encountered error messages.
Someone posed a similar question here.  So I have tried using:
Block[{\[Infinity]=1*^1},ListContourPlot[{{x,y,z1/z2}..}]]
But this did not work.  I also tried the following:
Block[{1/0=1*^1},ListContourPlot[{{x,y,z1/z2}..}]]
But here 1/0 is not a symbol so I get another error.  So alternatively I tried the following:
Block[{Symbol["Indeterminate"]=1*^1},ListContourPlot[{{x,y,z1/z2}..}]]
And again this did not work.  I am running out of ideas any help please?
Here are excerpts of the data I am manipulating:

data1 = 0,2000,100.94117647058823
100,2000,100.58823529411765
200,2000,101.
300,2000,105.82352941176471
400,2000,101.6470588235294
500,2000,105.82352941176471
600,2000,91.70588235294117
700,2000,82.94117647058823
800,2000,63.11764705882353
900,2000,46.8235294117647
1000,2000,27.470588235294116
1100,2000,15.058823529411764
1200,2000,6.
1300,2000,1.2352941176470589
1400,2000,0.17647058823529413
1500,2000,0.
1600,2000,0.058823529411764705
1700,2000,0.
1800,2000,0.058823529411764705
1900,2000,0.058823529411764705
2000,2000,0.058823529411764705
2100,2000,0.
2200,2000,0.
2300,2000,0.
2400,2000,0.
2500,2000,0.
2600,2000,0.
2700,2000,0.
2800,2000,0.
2900,2000,0.
3000,2000,0.

and

data2 = 0,2000,149.
100,2000,148.94117647058823
200,2000,150.41176470588235
300,2000,154.7058823529412
400,2000,150.64705882352942
500,2000,154.23529411764707
600,2000,141.94117647058823
700,2000,137.76470588235293
800,2000,126.58823529411765
900,2000,118.88235294117646
1000,2000,99.82352941176471
1100,2000,89.47058823529412
1200,2000,78.29411764705883
1300,2000,66.3529411764706
1400,2000,52.8235294117647
1500,2000,43.1764705882353
1600,2000,28.705882352941178
1700,2000,20.941176470588236
1800,2000,14.470588235294118
1900,2000,9.294117647058824
2000,2000,5.9411764705882355
2100,2000,3.411764705882353
2200,2000,1.7058823529411764
2300,2000,0.5882352941176471
2400,2000,0.11764705882352941
2500,2000,0.058823529411764705
2600,2000,0.
2700,2000,0.
2800,2000,0.
2900,2000,0.
3000,2000,0.

ps - ideally I would like to keep a record of where I encounter 1/0 in the contour plot, maybe shaded red in an otherwise gray scale plot.

It's better to show us some sample data to play with. Anyway, here's a hint: check 1/0 // FullForm

This question is similar to: How to replace one numerical constant with another?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65910/1871

@xzczd I have included some data in my post now and I have looked at your suggested post but the solution there didn't work for me (mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174556/how-to-replace-one-numerical-constant-with-another)

How do you use the solution? Please show us the complete code sample so we can check what's wrong. Also, your data1 and data2 are not properly formatted.

And after a second look, I think the question needs further clarification. The unclear part is: what's the goal of this question? Avoid the warning message? Replace ComplexInfinity, Indeterminate, etc. with certain number? Understand why your attempt fails? Or color the non-numeric value red? Or something else?

I think the question can be improved, but it's good enough to leave it open. @Richard please [edit] your question to improve as much as you can. Please address the issues raised in the comments. Also explain how is your question different from the ones pointed out in the comments.

Here is one way you can do this, replacing Indeterminate values with None:
Generate some dummy data:
data1 = Catenate@Table[{x, y, RandomInteger[{0, 9}]}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}];
data2 = Catenate@Table[{x, y, RandomInteger[{0, 9}]}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}];

Use MapThread to generate your plot data, replace every list item that does not evaluate to a number in the last coordinate with None:
pltData = Quiet[MapThread[
Flatten[{#1[[;; 2]], #1[[3]]/#2[[3]]}] &, {data1, data2}]] /. {x_,
  y_, z_} /; Not[NumberQ[z]] :> {x, y, None}

Plot this, and apply some formatting to visualize the missing data as red:
ListContourPlot[pltData, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors", Background -> Red, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> True, Frame -> False]



Actually it's not necessary to replace Indeterminate with None, the outputs are the same :)
