# Where in the documentation can I find a list of function argument types?

Tags: function-construction

Recently, I learned that it is possible to assign "types" to function arguments in the definition of a function.  Suppose I have a function `stringFun` that does some operation (e.g., `StringSplit`) on an input string `str`.  I could define the function in this way:

```
stringFun[str_] := StringSplit[str]
```

Or, I could define the argument `str_` as being of type `String`:

```
stringFun[str_String] := StringSplit[str]
```

What other argument "types" exist in Mathematica?  Can I use, for example, `Real`, `List`, or `Table`?  I am using Mathematica 7, and I am having some difficulty locating a list of "types" in the documentation.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well, since [every object in *Mathematica* has a **head**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html)... you can always write your functions so that it only works on objects with certain heads.

Comment: Related [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/how-to-create-strong-types/)

Comment: I find the premise of this question potentially misleading, esp to newer users of Mathematica. (But it's still a good question to ask!!!) You *can't* '...assign "types" to function arguments...' but you *can* filter which arguments can be passed to the RHS of your function. This is an important distinction, IMO.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The notation `foo[x_bar] := ...` merely states that you're defining the function `foo` only for arguments that have the head `bar`. Here's a silly example to show you that:

```
Clear@foo
foo[x_bar] := First@x
foo[bar[2, 3]]
(* 2 *)

foo[{2, 3}]
(* foo[{2, 3}] *)
```

Note that the head can be any symbol (function) and not necessarily types such as string/real/integer, etc. Since everything in *Mathematica* is an expression which has a `Head` and possibly several `Part`s, you can create your own patterns to work only with certain heads as in the example above.

---

### Differences between patterns with specific heads (`_h`) and equivalent pattern tests (`_?hQ`)

Probably a more important distinction is the difference between specifying heads in patterns and pattern tests for the same head, i.e. between, say, `x_Integer` and `x_?IntegerQ`. On the surface, they behave the same:

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_Integer] := x^2
g[x_?IntegerQ] := x^2

{f[4], g[4]}
(* {16, 16} *)
```

but they have two important distinctions that are worth highlighting

#### 1. Behaviour in functions with the `HoldAll` attribute

If your functions have the `HoldAll` attribute (or any `Hold*` attribute that has an equivalent effect on the pattern), the arguments are not evaluated by default. The latter form (using `PatternTest`) forces evaluation of the argument and hence is useful in this case. For example, slightly modifying the above:

```
Clear[f, g]
SetAttributes[#, HoldAll] & /@ {f, g};
f[x_Integer] := x^2
g[x_?IntegerQ] := x^2

{f[2 + 2], g[2 + 2]}
(* {f[2 + 2], 16} *)
```

#### 2. Calls to the main evaluator

As Leonid notes, matches (or not) for patterns of the type `x_foo` are easily established by the pattern matcher, which can be very fast. On the other hand, the presence of a pattern test passes the evaluation to the main evaluator and introduces a sub-evaluation during the pattern matching and this can result in a big performance hit. As a simple example, consider the following:

```
Cases[Hold@{2, {Print["Evaluated!"]}, Pause[1.]}, _Integer, ∞] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000028, {2}} *)
```

You can see that using the `_Integer` pattern did not result in evaluation of either the `Print` statement or the `Pause` statement. Now compare:

```
Cases[Hold@{2, {Print["Evaluated!"]}, Pause[1.]}, _?IntegerQ, ∞] // AbsoluteTiming
(* Evaluated!
   Evaluated!
   Evaluated!
   {2.000453, {2}} *)
```

You can see that the `Print` statement was evaluated as `Cases` walked through the expression tree (three times in total) and the `Pause` statement was executed twice.

So the take away message is that if you want to do something like strong type checking, then avoid `PatternTests`.

Comment: +1, nice explanation. I would probably add that the behavior of functions with `HoldAll` attribute is but one example of a more general and simple principle: patterns of type `x_h` are purely syntactic and the fact of their match can be established by the pattern-matcher alone, while the presence of `Condition` and `PatternTest` signal the call to the main evaluator. That is, every pattern having them as its part(s) induces sub-evaluations during the pattern-matching, just to establish the fact of the match.

Comment: This has also a considerable impact on performance, see e.g. [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/how-are-memberq-and-freeq-so-fast/1420#1420). This may become relevant in the context of typing and type-checking, since sometimes type-checks using `PatternTest` can bring an unacceptable performance hit. Finally, truly strong typing should not IMO use `PatternTest` since this makes it dependent on main evaluator, while using `x_h` makes this quite rigid and independent on anything outside the pattern-matcher.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks, I'll add that info in shortly. I finally realize what you mean by your term "syntactic patterns" :) Even though I was aware of the behaviour of `x_h` and `x_?h` it never occurred to me that this was important enough to maintain the distinction, but now it's clear :)

Comment: No problem :). Just thought it would be useful to mention the general reason / mechanism.

Answer (score 5):

As J.M. pointed out: What you are matching is the `Head`of the expression. So basically you can match anything you like.

For example:

```
Head /@ {1, "a str", \[Pi], myWrap[x]}
(* ==>
{Integer, String, Symbol, myWrap}
*)
```

So you can define a function that only accepts "wrapped" expressions:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[exp_myWrap] := exp[[1]];
f /@ {1, "a str", Pi, myWrap[x]}

(* ==> {f[1], f["a str"], f[Pi], x} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

To save me having to remember the syntax each time, I have this current list of names in an initialization section (Or put this at the top of you  notebook, or any where you want to use this each time):

```
(*definitions used for parameter checking*)

integerStrictPositive = (IntegerQ[#] && # > 0 &);
integerPositive = (IntegerQ[#] && # >= 0 &);
numericStrictPositive = (Element[#, Reals] && # > 0 &);
numericPositive = (Element[#, Reals] && # >= 0 &);
numericStrictNegative = (Element[#, Reals] && # < 0 &);
numericNegative = (Element[#, Reals] && # <= 0 &);
bool = (Element[#, Booleans] &);
numeric = (Element[#, Reals] &);
integer = (Element[#, Integers] &);
```

Then in the function definiitions, I use the above as

```
listClass[
  $size_?integer, $r0_?numericStrictPositive,
  .... ]:=Module[{},.....]
```

and so on.

This made it easier for me to use these checks since it a little easier to use as I do not have to look up the correct syntax each time as I did before.

I have a note in my FAQ on this with more documentation here http://alturl.com/a3p66

Comment: I presume you know the functions `Positive[]` and `NonNegative[]`, and just chose not to use them?

Comment: Well, `SetAttributes[g, HoldAll]; integerStrictPositive = (IntegerQ[#] && Positive[#] &); g[x_?integerStrictPositive] := x^2; {g[5 + 10], g[5 - 10]}` behaves as I expected it to...