# How to remove elements from a list that are less than a certain number?

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list like:

```
list = {23,21,18,15,13,12,10,9,8,7,7,5}
```

How can I remove numbers from that list so that no number less than 13 is on it without hardcoding, so if the list were different it would still remove any numbers less than 13?

I tried using the position like:

```
position = Position[list, 2]
listNew = list[[1;;position]]
```

It doesn't work because position's output is

```
{{10}}
```

Comment: closely related [**180**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180/5478)

Comment: A built-in function to remove elements from a list would be `DeleteCases`. This should evaluate to what you are looking for: `DeleteCases[list,_?(# < 13 &)]`.

Comment: What about marking this as a duplicate of [24167](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24167/5478)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
list = {23, 21, 18, 15, 13, 12, 10, 9, 8, 7, 7, 5};
Select[list, # >= 13 &]
```

> {23, 21, 18, 15, 13}

**Reference:**
[Select](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)
[Selecting parts of Expression with Function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SelectingPartsOfExpressionsWithFunctions.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
Pick[list, UnitStep[list - 13], 1]
```

$\ $`{23, 21, 18, 15, 13}`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `Position`

```
pos = Flatten @ Position[list, _?(# >= 13 &)]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

```
list[[pos]]
```

> {23, 21, 18, 15, 13}

Since your list is ordered it's more efficient to write

```
pos = First@FirstPosition[list, _?(# <= 13 &)]
```

> 5

```
list[[;; pos]]
```

> {23, 21, 18, 15, 13}

Comment: ...but if you like patterns so much, then use `Cases[]` instead. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Replacement rules are another option - just for exposure to new ideas. This will be slow on big lists.

```
list = {23,21,18,15,13,12,10,9,8,7,7,5}
newList = list/. _?(# < 13 &)->Sequence[]
```

gives `{23, 21, 18, 15, 13}`

Comment: Since 10.2 one can use `Nothing` instead of `Sequence[]`.