# Why is AllTrue much slower than VectorQ?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, version-10

This seems to be a theme with V10, a new function dedicated to a specific task doesn't live up to expectation performance-wise. Mr. Wizard has already uncovered 2 such functions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54853/positionindex-is-horribly-slow/54865#54865) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55294/deleteduplicatesby-is-not-performing-as-id-hoped-am-i-missing-something). So how about `AllTrue` versus `VectorQ`? From the docs

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

We're interested in the second usage of `VectorQ` here, which is the same as the purpose of `AllTrue`. A quick test shows that `VectorQ` annihilates `AllTrue` when it comes to performance e.g.

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

AccurateTiming[AllTrue[Range[10^6], IntegerQ]]
```

> 0.20069455

While for `VectorQ`:

```
AccurateTiming[VectorQ[Range[10^6], IntegerQ]]
```

> 0.00214923153

That is a two order of magnitude performance increase over `AllTrue`. Using `BenchMarkPlot` from the useful `GeneralUtilities` package we observe the following:

```
BenchmarkPlot[
 {VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &, AllTrue[#, IntegerQ] &},
 Range[#] &,
 PowerRange[10, 10^8],
 "IncludeFits" -> True, PlotRange -> Full
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, why is `AllTrue` slow compared to `VectorQ`?

Comment: It is clear both from the absolute timings, and the complexity, that  `VectorQ[..., IntegerQ]` has been specially overloaded on packed arrays to be constant time. In other words, the top-level evaluator doesn't actually evaluate `IntegerQ` on every element in a list here. But `AllTrue` has no choice, being more general function, and has a linear complexity, as it should.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. Thanks that explains it. Do you want to post that as an answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: Re: post vs delete - let's see what others think. Actually, this issue has been already discussed in another place here on SE (as a sub-topic of a wider discussion), but I can't find it now.

Comment: Note that `Range[10^6]` is slower than `VectorQ`.  You might want to do the comparison with the range stored in a variable, `data = Range[10^6]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I don't understand. I'm not comparing `Range` to `VectorQ`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in `AccurateTiming[VectorQ[Range[10^6], IntegerQ]]`, computing `Range[10^6]` accounts for most of the time.

Comment: @Leonid A stretch, as I don't think it is the same issue, but by chance were you thinking of this?: [(1418)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1418)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Alas, no. There was some other discussion, where I was mentioning the speed of `VectorQ[..., NumericQ]` in my answer. I seem to remember that Szabolcs also posted an answer there, also mentioning this.

Comment: `AllTrue` has not been optimized in version 10.0.1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I noticed too. I guess since poor optimization is not really a bug, we'll just have to hope that someone at WRI notices this post.

Comment: I think they have a lot "on their plates" at this time and optimizations are probably a much lower priority.  I suppose `PositionIndex` was fixed only because it got a lot of attention, specifically Tali's.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you're probably right. As an aside, I also noticed that a lot of the `Region` function bugs I uncovered were not addressed in this update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess I'll answer my question. As Leonid Shifrin alluded to in the comment, `AllTrue` is actually a more general function than `VectorQ` and this has various consequences:

(1) `VectorQ` is overloaded to work efficiently with packed arrays which is evident from my benchmark above.
(2) If we append a non-integer to the example in the question, we no longer have a packed array and the complexity of both functions are now the same O(n):

```
BenchmarkPlot[
 {VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &, AllTrue[#, IntegerQ] &},
 Append[Range[#], 3.4] &,
 PowerRange[10, 10^8],
 "IncludeFits" -> True, PlotRange -> Full
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It appears that `VectorQ` is still slightly faster than `AllTrue` maybe someone can shed more light on this scenario.
(3) `AllTrue` returns symbolic results if test is applied to a symbol, this must lead to more overhead from such symbolic preprocessing.

Comment: I think the growing wisdom is: *wait until version 10.0.2 to upgrade.*

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I agree. It's looking like v10 was released before it was ready for primetime.

Comment: I can't plot the graph like yours with your code now and my mma version is 10.1.Why?Can you help me?Thank you.