# How do I check if any element in a list is positive?

Tags: list-manipulation

As a simple example of what I would like to do, suppose I have a list `a` of all real numbers.  I would like to perform a simple check to see if *some* element of `a` is positive.  Of course, I could do this with a simple loop, but I feel as if *Mathematica* would have a more efficient way of doing this, in the spirit of functional programming.  Is there, or do I just have to do this with a clumsy loop:

```
test=False; For[counter=1;counter<=Length[a];counter++;If[a[[counter]]>0,test=True;];];
```

Comment: A general guidance for how to "map" loop constructions to functional ones is found in this question, see ["alternatives to loops"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/1635)

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  You've been away some while.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry about that.  Quite honestly, for some reason I thought I had accepted an answer awhile ago, and didn't realize that was not the case until yesterday when I got a notification that I had received a badge for the question.  My bad.

Comment: Jonathan, my comment wasn't meant to complain.  Frankly I didn't expect to see you on the site again as you had been away for a while.  I appreciated you taking the effort to Accept an answer despite the fact that you're apparently not spending a lot of time on the site these days.  So thanks again, and welcome back.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, simply test if the maximum value in the list is Positive:

```
Positive @ Max @ a
```

Speed comparison with other methods that were posted:

```
timeAvg = 
  Function[func,
    Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}],
    HoldFirst];

a = RandomInteger[{-1*^7, 2}, 1*^7];

MemberQ[a, _?Positive] // timeAvg

Total@UnitStep[-a] =!= Length@a // timeAvg

Positive@Max@a // timeAvg
```

> 0.593
>
> 0.0624
>
> 0.01148

---

#### Early-exit methods

Although very fast, especially with packed lists, the method above does scan the entire list with no possibility for an early exit when a positive elements occurs near the front of the list.  In that case a test that does not scan the entire list may be faster, such as the one that R.M posted.  Exploring such methods I propose this:

```
! VectorQ[a, NonPositive]
```

Unlike `MemberQ`, `VectorQ` does not unpack a packed list.

Timings compared to `MemberQ` and `Max`, first with an early positive appearance:

```
SeedRandom[1]
a = RandomReal[{-1*^7, 1000}, 1*^7];

Positive @ Max @ a        // timeAvg
! VectorQ[a, NonPositive] // timeAvg
MemberQ[a, _?Positive]    // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.008736
>
> 0.00013984
>
> 0.2528
> ```

(Most of the `MemberQ` time is spent unpacking the list.)

Then no positive appearance (full scan):

```
a = RandomInteger[{-1*^7, 0}, 1*^7];

Positive @ Max @ a        // timeAvg
! VectorQ[a, NonPositive] // timeAvg
MemberQ[a, _?Positive]    // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.01148
>
> 1.544
>
> 2.528
> ```

Finally a mid-range appearance of a positive value in an unpacked list:

```
a = RandomReal[{-50, 0}, 1*^7];
a[[5*^6]] = 1;

Positive @ Max @ a        // timeAvg
! VectorQ[a, NonPositive] // timeAvg
MemberQ[a, _?Positive]    // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.212
>
> 0.702
>
> 1.045
> ```

Comment: You got me, +1 ;)

Comment: @Rojo you'll get me next time.

Comment: You surprised me, didn't know you were prowling around

Comment: @Rojo *prowling* now is it? :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard nice timing - fast machine, is it?

Comment: @Yves Intel i5-2500K at 4.6GHz - it seems to work well for *Mathematica*.  Also, v7 usually tests faster than v8.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard beat my i7 2820QM by about 15% on Windows 7 and V8.04.

Answer (score 22):

I think the canonical way would be to use an "any" function which you can find in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/916/5) question. Using a variant of [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/922/5), you can use

```
MemberQ[list, _?Positive]
```

to check if any element is positive.

Comment: A variation: `MemberQ[Sign[list], 1]`

Comment: Very elegant..!

Comment: Welcome to the 20K club.

Comment: @J.M. I cannot find a case where that is best.  `Positive @ Max @ a` is always faster.  The strength of `MemberQ[list, _?Positive]` is with an unpacked list where a positive element occurs near the beginning.

Comment: +1.  By the way, I've noticed a lot of Mathematica functions end with "Q", and it seems like all such functions are meant to answer a "Yes or No Question".  Is this indeed what the "Q" stands for, "question"?

Comment: Also, could you explain the use of `_?` here?  I can't seem to find this in the documentation.

Comment: @JonathanGleason Yes, most `*Q` functions yield `True` or `False`. I don't know for sure if `Q` stands for "question", but that's kind of how I reasoned it too. Regarding `_?`, the relevant doc page is [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html). In short, it tests to see if the pattern (here [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html)) satisfies the `True/False` test. Reading the related references and tutorials on [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Patterns.html) will also be helpful

Comment: @Jonathan regarding `_?` also see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121).

Comment: This is very cute. +1a

Answer (score 18):

```
l = RandomChoice[Range[-100, 1], 50];
```

Simplest to understand is

```
Or @@ Positive[l]
```

Perhaps faster for long lists is

```
Total@UnitStep[-l] =!= Length@l
```

Comment: Damn, too quick for me

Answer (score 10):

The fastest I could come up with, using the undocumented `` Compile`GetElement `` for indexing (it's the fastest even without):

```
f = Compile[
  {{l, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[
   {max = -1},
   Do[
    If[max < Compile`GetElement[l, i], max = Compile`GetElement[l, i]],
    {i, 1, Length@l}];
   max > 0
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]
```

Using `timeAvg` from Mr.Wizard's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8652/16),

```
MemberQ[a, _?Positive] // timeAvg
Total@UnitStep[-a] =!= Length@a // timeAvg
Positive@Max@a // timeAvg
f[a] // timeAvg
(*
1.38034
0.114101
0.0187749
0.00830531
*)
```

Comment: No fair!  Blasted v8 compile-to-C...

Comment: I get error messages for `RandomReal` input. Should timing include `Compile`overhead as well?

Comment: @Yves  he compiled for `_Integer` values; you'd need to compile a separate function for `_Real` values, then craft a function to select between them, as well as intelligently handle lists that are not packed and may contain mixed types.  I don't think compilation overhead should be included in timings unless it uses pre-calculation.

Comment: @YvesKlett As Mr.W says it's compiled for `Integers`, and would need to be recompiled for reals. I don't know if timing should include compilation overhead; to be honest, I offer this is what I'd do if I needed it to be as fast as possible. It's clearly not leveraging Mathematica's strengths, nor is particularly pretty or clever.

Comment: How about a short-circuited version of the loop that keeps testing ``Compile`GetElement[l, i]`` until it fins something positive? (i.e., use `Break[]`) somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

This is even faster than acl's code, for data with positive elements appearing early on, because it stops as soon as it finds a positive.

```
ff = Compile[{{l, _Real, 1}},
Module[{i = 1, n = Length@l},
While[Compile`GetElement[l, i] <= 0. && i <= n, i = i + 1];
i <= n], "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Since the OP specifies real numbers I've changed acl's function to take reals:

```
f = Compile[{{l, _Real, 1}}, 
Module[{max = -1.},
Do[If[max < Compile`GetElement[l, i], max = Compile`GetElement[l, i]], {i, 1, Length@l}];
max > 0], "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Here is some timing data where I've inserted a single positive element into the list at varying positions:

```
b = RandomReal[{-1*^7, 0}, 1*^7];

timedata = Table[
a = b; a[[10^j]] = 1.0; {10^j,
{MemberQ[a, _?Positive] // timeAvg,
Total@UnitStep[-a] =!= Length@a // timeAvg,
Positive@Max@a // timeAvg,
f[a] // timeAvg,
ff[a] // timeAvg}}
, {j, 1, 7}];

ListLogLogPlot[Transpose[Thread /@ timedata], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: This is surely the optimal way to approach this problem (though likely overkill for the OP).  Unfortunately I cannot test it in v7, and as a rule I don't vote for v8-only answers.  Not because such answers are not good, but because I think it is important to test things, and it would be unfair to vote for *some* v8 answers and not others.

Comment: Somehow after @Mr.Wizard's review no one likes my approach. I'll go and have a proper cry ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I agree that it's overkill :-) Especially as the OP was explicitly trying to avoid clumsy loops.

Comment: @YvesKlett, it's not so much that I don't *like* your answer, I just thought it was essentially the same algorithm Rojo's `UnitStep` approach. By the way, why `Tr` and not `Total` ?

Comment: Tr is shorter ;-) although similar in spirit the timing is different for `Clip` and `UnitStep` approaches.

Comment: This is what I've thought first. I'm amazed it is 5th answer not 2nd. @Mr.Wizard It deserves vote for a method :) I would say that testing all elements when OP wants to know if any is positive seems an overkill ;)

Comment: @Kuba, the OP was specifically asking for a functional method, so it's not surprising that this procedural loop is not highly voted :-)

Answer (score 6):

To add a bit variety, you could try:

```
l = RandomChoice[Range[-100, 1], 5000000];

Tr[Clip[l, {0, Infinity}]] > 0
```

The timing for different methods of input shows that, unsurprisingly, some solutions are very dependent on the average number of positive elements and others not so much. @Mr.Wizard´s `Positive@Max@a` and @acl´s compiled `f[a]` seem to win every time.

```
f = Compile[{{l, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Module[{max = -1}, 
    Do[If[max < Compile`GetElement[l, i], 
      max = Compile`GetElement[l, i]], {i, 1, Length@l}];
    max > 0], CompilationTarget -> "C"];

timeAvg = 
  Function[func, 
   Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 
     15}], HoldFirst];

a = RandomInteger[{-1*^7, 1}, 1*^7];

MemberQ[a, _?Positive] // timeAvg
Or @@ Positive[a] // timeAvg
Total@UnitStep[-a] =!= Length@a // timeAvg
Tr[Clip[a, {0, Infinity}]] > 0 // timeAvg
Positive@Max@a // timeAvg
f[a] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 4.072   
> 0.546     
> 0.0716     
> 0.04056     
> 0.01748     
> 0.01048
> ```

```
a = RandomInteger[{-1*^7, 1*^7}, 1*^7];

MemberQ[a, _?Positive] // timeAvg
Or @@ Positive[a] // timeAvg
Total@UnitStep[-a] =!= Length@a // timeAvg
Tr[Clip[a, {0, Infinity}]] > 0 // timeAvg
Positive@Max@a // timeAvg
f[a] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.561     
> 0.359     
> 0.078     
> 1.748     
> 0.01684     
> 0.01048
> ```

Comment: If you can find a case where this is faster than `Positive @ Max @ list` you'll get my vote.  If not it's just considerable complication, IMHO.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It definitely is a complication and I  do not hold high hopes for getting that vote.

Comment: @YvesKlett, the reason for the much longer timing for your code in the second example is that you are adding up a large number of large integers. If you set the upper bound of `Clip` to 1 instead of infinity it is quite a bit quicker.

Comment: @SimonWoods I thought so too but the timings are not really conclusive. Using Reals for the bounds masssively slows `Clip` down, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that uses `LengthWhile`:

```
test[list_] := Length@list != LengthWhile[list, NonPositive]
```

This test works well for lists that contain a positive element near the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Since V 10.0 we can also use `AnyTrue`:

```
AnyTrue[{-1, -1, 1}, # > 0 &]
```

True

```
AnyTrue[{-1, -1}, # > 0 &]
```

False

Answer (score 2):

A point-free style

```
{-1, -1, 1} // AnyTrue[Positive]
```