# List manipulation - End loop

Tags: list-manipulation

Given are two matrices (a & b). I want to end the For-loop if **all** values in the matrix (a minus b) are smaller than 7, in contrast to **any** value in the matrix (a minus b) is smaller than 7. Can anybody help me with this problem?

```
For[Q = 0, Q <= 20, Q += 1,
  Print[Q];
  Print[a = {{40, 40, 40}, {40, 40, 40}, {40, 40, 40}}];
  Print[b = Q {{4, 4, 4}, {4, 3, 4}, {4, 4, 4}}];

   compare[matrix_, length_, width_, value_] := 
   Module[{state}, state = False; For[i = 1, i <= length, i++, 
     For[j = 1, j <= width, j++, 
      If[matrix[[i, j]] < value, state = True]]]; Return[state]];

  If[compare[a - b, 3, 3, 7], Break[],]];
```

Comment: Perhaps `Max[a - b] < 7`

Comment: Related: [(8650)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8650/121)

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
compare[a_, b_] := And @@ (Less[#, 7] & /@ Flatten@(a - b))
```

Then

```
For[Q = 0, Q <= 20, Q += 1, Print[Q];
 Print[a = {{40, 40, 40}, {40, 40, 40}, {40, 40, 40}}];
 Print[b = Q {{4, 4, 4}, {4, 3, 4}, {4, 4, 4}}];
 If[compare[a, b], Break[]]]
```

Stops at `Q=12`:

> {{40,40,40},{40,40,40},{40,40,40}}
>
> {{48,48,48},{48,36,48},{48,48,48}}

Alternative that may or may not be faster (other members are much, much better at optimizing for speed, if you have this problem you should say so):

```
compare2[a_, b_] := ! Or @@ Positive@UnitStep@Flatten@(a - b - 7)
```

Comment: Replace 7 with 0.001? :P

Comment: Also see the comment by Simon Woods, which is a simpler and faster test.

Comment: Thanks. Now I want to end the For-loop if the difference between A and B at every point in the matrix is less than 0.001(Aij-Bij). How can I fix this?

Comment: ij is given I suppose? Replace 7 with `0.001(A[[i,j]]-B[[i,j]])`

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is to print only the matrices that comply with the constraint (as the last printed are the first exception), perhaps (using the compare function of Anon):

```
compare[a_, b_] := And @@ (Less[#, 7] & /@ Flatten@(a - b));
a = {{40, 40, 40}, {40, 40, 40}, {40, 40, 40}};
b = {{4, 4, 4}, {4, 3, 4}, {4, 4, 4}};
Q = 0;
While[compare[a, Q b] == False, Print[Q]; Print[a]; Print[Q b]; Q++]
```

Comment: Of course you could just change the comparison test to the beginning of the sequence of commands.

Comment: Or put `Print` inside the `If`. (I don't see how putting it in the beginning would solve it.)

Comment: @Anon thank you and sorry, yes it would only work if a and b, Q ( hence Qb) were defined outside the loops and the first statement was the comparison, then it would break once test was true and before printing but as structured I am in error.