# Generalization to AllTrue, AnyTrue and NoneTrue

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, counting

I am wondering if there is a natural Mathematica way to generalize those functions. To be specific, All three functions `AllTrue`, `AnyTrue` and `NoneTrue` return a Boolean value when a list of length `L` contains certain number of elements satisfying a predicate.

For example, `AllTrue` returns true when the number of elements satisfying the predicate is `L` while `NoneTrue` returns true when the number is `0`.
On the contrary, `AnyTrue` returns true when the number is at least `1`.

I am considering the generalization `SomeTrue[ list, pred, n]` that
it returns true when the number is at least `n`.

Another generalization might be `SomeTrue[ list, pred, {n}]` that
it returns true when the number is exactly `n`.

One natural way I can think of is just using `Count` function to calculate the number and compare the criterion but it does not allow the early exit(i.e., every element should be checked even for the case where the result is determined in the early stage).

For people like me migrating from procedural language, the algorithm might be obvious using `For` loop with counters and early `return` statements.
It would be nice if you can show some examples with truly Mathematica way to attack such problems.

Comment: Note: kguler mentioned `BooleanCountingFunction`.  Unfortunately it doesn't appear applicable here as I cannot think of a way to give it early-exit behavior, so one might as well use `Count`.

Comment: I'd go with `While` myself. One could use `Scan` and `THrow/Catch`, say. But really I don't see an early exit method that does not, at heart, emulate procedural code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) is fairly close to this already, notably including early exit behavior, so perhaps:

```
someTrue[list_, pred_, {m_} | n_] :=
  n + m == Length @ Select[list, pred, 1 n + m]
```

Test:

```
someTrue[Range@10, PrimeQ, 3]
someTrue[Range@10, PrimeQ, 5]
someTrue[Range@10, PrimeQ, {4}]
someTrue[Range@10, PrimeQ, {2}]
```

> ```
> True
>
> False
>
> True
>
> False
> ```

---

The code above is me trying to be clever with [vanishing patterns.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44084/121)  The longer but more legible form:

```
someTrue[list_, pred_, n_]   := n == Length @ Select[list, pred, n]
someTrue[list_, pred_, {n_}] := n == Length @ Select[list, pred, n + 1]
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about the variants of `Select`. Also thanks for the introduction of vanishing patterns which I have not encountered yet :).

Comment: I see; vanishing patterns necessitates the inclusion of `1` in `1 n + m`. Also, clever use of `Length@Select[..., n + 1]` to test for exactly `n` length. +1

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, and thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to implement this without `Select`, but with `VectorQ`. If you don't want to duplicate memory, then `Select` could be dangerous.

My idea was to count the number of times `pred` was true and exit once it hit's the specified threshold.

```
SomeTrue[list_, pred_, n_Integer] := Module[{i = 0},
  !VectorQ[list, (If[pred[#], i++]; i < n)&]
]

SomeTrue[list_, pred_, {n_Integer}] := Module[{i = 0},
  VectorQ[list, (If[pred[#], i++]; i < n+1)&] && i == n
]
```

Comment: +1 for the idea but it would be preferred to use `Module` instead of `Block`.

Comment: On unpacked lists `Select` has a significant advantage being about five times as fast as this.  However `VectorQ` does not unpack therefore this saves memory there as well and also avoids the time taken to unpack.

Comment: Could you elaborate the statement "If you don't want to duplicate memory"?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Could you explain why `Module` is preferred in this case?

Comment: @Sungmin (1) `Select` gathers a new list of results that pass the test function, and this new list takes memory.  Further `Select` unpacks packed arrays therefore if your list is a large packed array it will first be expanded to several times its original size; `VectorQ` does not unpack.  See: [(8652)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8652/121).

Comment: @Sungmin (2) `Module` is preferred because it is the correct tool to create a localized Symbol for e.g. a counter.  `Block` modifies the value of the global Symbol (`i`).  This means that if for example you define `ex = {3, h, i, j, k};` and then do `SomeTrue[ex, NumericQ, 2]` you get `True` even though there is only one numeric element in `ex`.  This happens because inside the `Block` `i` *has* a numeric value.  This collision is avoided by using `Module`.  I used to misuse `Block` quite often and I can tell you from experience it leads to nasty bugs.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes you are obviously correct about `Block`.  I was originally playing around with a recursive idea and forgot about the it when I abandoned the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
If[Count[Boole[list], 1] == n, True, False]
```

where n is the number of Trues you require

Comment: No early exit here. In fact the question specifically mentions `Count` as a suboptimal solution.

Comment: Also you don't need `If` -- `Count[Boole[list], 1] == n` will do.

Comment: Here's an Experiment you might like to try: `(* This generates a list of 1 million random Boolean equations *)
blist = Table[ RandomChoice[{Equal, Unequal, Greater, Less}][ RandomInteger[{1, 100}], RandomInteger[{1, 100}]], {i, 1, 10^6}]; (* This checks to see if number of True results is between 300,000 and 350,000 *) 300000 < Count[Boole[blist], 1] < 350000` Of course you may change these parameters and see if it is fast enough.

Comment: If the test function is fast and you are checking most of the elements anyway `Count` is fine.  However sometimes the test function is slow and you *don't* want to run it on all of the elements.  For example consider `mers = 2^Range[5000] - 1;` and the performance of `someTrue[mers, PrimeQ, 7]`, then compare your method.

Comment: Tried this method for Mersene Primes up to 2^5000 -1,Around 10 secs it took. mersprlist = Table[PrimeQ[2^i - 1], {i, 1, 5000}];
Count[Boole[mersprlist], 1]

Comment: And my method takes a fraction of a second.  That's the point.