# How in Mathematica, would I define a function that takes arguments much like one would in an object orientated language

Tags: function-construction

I would know how to write a function in object orientated language, just I don't know how to do this in mathematica, in an OOP I would define a function like this:

```
int rss = null;

 int Define_RSS(int a, int b, int c, int d){

  int output = (code functionality)
  rss = (some more functionality)
  return output
}
```

I would like to know how to do the equivalent in mathematica.

Comment: I voted to close. Upon reading the response by @2012rcampion I now see the question might have merit. I still don't understand the subject header though. If this all gets clarified I'd be happy to retract that vote.

Comment: okay, allow me to re-articulate, I have an issue with this, its a form of dyslexia, hold up

Comment: I notice there is a sibling question on Wolfram Community, and that one does have explanation as to what specifically was being attempted. In any case, this new subject header suffices to make clear what was wanted for the question at hand.

Comment: I still find the title and text not fitting the actual content very well. I don't see anything that would qualify "object orientated" in that function definition. It would probably best fit the term "procedural" as it has a side effect which doesn't make it really fit "functional" as well. As it changes a global variable I wouldn't consider it a felicitous construct in any programming paradigm I've ever heard of...

Comment: Ah well im still studying, when I have a better understanding and use of the terminology I will update the title and edit my post a touch more, I meant perhaps "how sdo I go about doing something in mathematica that in OOP language I would do like this..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rss = None;

DefineRSS[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Module[
        {output=(* code functionality *)},
        rss = (* some more functionality *);
        output
    ]
```

First we initialize the variable `rss` to `None`.  Then we define (using `SetDelayed`) a function `DefineRSS` (Note we can't use `_` because Mathematica will interpret that as a pattern).  We use `Module` to define a temporary variable, set `rss`, and then evaluate the temporary variable.

Note that if you need more than one line to define `output` (e.g., you define it iteratively in multiple operations) you can use this form:

```
DefineRSS[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Module[{output},
        output=(* code functionality *);
        output=(* even more functionality *);
        rss = (* some more functionality *);
        output
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple and concise answer.

Comment: Unless this is being used in a way I do not understand you should not use `Block` here but `Module` instead.  See [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71698/generalization-to-alltrue-anytrue-and-nonetrue/71798#comment196870_71798) for more.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Total coincidence, I happened to check just after you posted.  I got in the habit of using `Block` before I learned the difference between it and `Module`, thanks for the correction.

Comment: One possible improvement would be to make `DefineRSS` `HoldFirst` and place symbols needing modification explicitly in a list for that first arg (or, if only one as above, just pass that alone). That way variables are properly localized, even the ones being treated as "by reference" rather than "by value".

Comment: @Daniel Good point! Jethro, see this for related information: [(18737)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/121)