# Type declaration for list arguments

Tags: function-construction, data-types

How can I make

```
f[n_Integer]=2*n
```

valid for a list of integers? For example:

```
f[nlist_Integer] := 2*nlist[[1]]
```

does not work because because `nlist={1,3,2}` is not an integer.

**Edit**: Same question with `NumericQ` (which does not work as `Integer`)?

Comment: Related: [(6588)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6588/121) -- also see the many links therein.  And performance notes here may be useful: [(8650)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8650/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
F[listInt:{__Integer}]:=
```

The semicolon is just another way to name a pattern

Comment: By chance, I just found `nList_ /; VectorQ[nList, IntegerQ]` reading a question. Your suggestion is shorter.

Comment: How would you make it work with `NumericQ̀`?

Comment: `F[listInt:{__Integer}]`?

Comment: @belisarius Absolutely. It does not work with `Integers`.

Comment: ups... typo...sorry I was on my ipad

Comment: @anderstood `F[b : {__?NumericQ}]`?

Comment: @belisarius Indeed! Thank you both.