# How to use Contains functions on matrices?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, expression-test

I need a quick test to check if a large matrix contains any non-zeros.  The Contains functions work on Lists not matrices.

```
d1 = ConstantArray[0, 100];
d2 = ConstantArray[0, {100, 100}];
ContainsOnly[d1, {0}]
ContainsOnly[d2, {0}]
ContainsAny[d1, {0}]
ContainsAny[d2, {0}]
```

(*  True  False  True  False  *)

I know that I could use Flatten[], but Flatten appears to create another entire list in memory, which takes time and (worse) consumes memory:

```
n = 20000;
d2 = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
Print[Timing[ContainsOnly[Flatten@d2, {0}]]];
Print[Timing[d3 = Flatten[d2]][[1]]];
Print[Timing[ContainsOnly[d3, {0}]]];
```

(*   {2.46, True}   1.375   {0.75, True}   *)

Is there a way to just search the matrix instead of copying it into a Flatten[]'d list to search?

I ultimately just need to know if the matrix contains any non-zeros.  Hopefully, there's a method that will stop search once it finds a non-zero.

Comment: Directly from the docs: "`ContainsOnly[e1,e2]` 
yields `True` if `e1` contains only elements that appear in `e2`". Your `d2` - this is the `e1` - is a _list of lists_ of zeros - this list (the outer one) doesn't contain a `0` - `e2 == {0}` here -  i.e. `{0, ...., 0}` is not `0`. You can simply `ContainsOnly[Flatten@d2, {0}]` - yields `True`.

Comment: @corey979   Thanks.  But Flatten copies the matrix into a List, which consumes time and memory.  I added a bit to the Question to clarify why I didn't use Flatten.

Comment: `Count[d2, 0, Infinity]` if all you want is whether the array contains `0`.  If you also are interest in `0.`, use `Count[d2, (0 | 0.), Infinity]`.

Comment: If you know that you have only numbers, `Total[Abs[d2], Infinity]` gives a similar performance of 2.5 s. If you have only positive numbers then you can gain performance by using `Total[d2, Infinity]` (0.5 s)

Comment: @Felix  I know I'll only have positive integers. I feel like I should be able to to get similar performance to the .75s of my last example.

Comment: Then `Total[d2, Infinity]==0` gives even better performance.

Comment: @Felix  Yep, that's the fastest so far, but it seems like there's got to be something better.  All I want is to check if the array contains any non-zeros.

Comment: `MemberQ[d3, Except[0], {-1}]` only checks for non-zero elements, but it is slower than `Total`.

Comment: Max@d2==0 s/b pretty quick for "... know I'll only have positive integers" case you state.

Comment: @ciao  You are right!  Even when they aren't positive, Max[Abs[d2]]==0 is as fast a searching the Flatten[]'d list.  I think this was the Answer I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: Closely related: [(8650)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8650/121)

Answer (score 2):

The function `FirstCase[matrix,0,"No zero",2]` should do the trick quickly. It gives 0 if there is at least one 0 in the matrix and "No zero" otherwise. The good thing is (a) you don't have to flatten your matrix first and (b) it stops as soon as the first zero is found, so as long as the only zero is not hidden at the very last position, it doesn't even go through the whole matrix to answer your question.

```
matrix=Table[RandomReal[],{2000},{2000}];
```

Here
    `Timing[ContainsAny[Flatten[matrix],{0}]]`
gives on my laptop 4.4 seconds, while

```
Timing[FirstCase[matrix,0,"Non zero",2]]
```

gives 0.3 seconds i.e. about 10 times faster. If you have a zero early on in the matrix 'ContainsAny' is as slow as before, but FirstCase speeds up:

```
matrix[[223,445]]==0
Timing[FirstCase[matrix,0,"Non zero",2]
```

gives now 0.01 seconds.

Comment: Normally I'd use `RepeatedTiming[]` or at least `AbsoluteTiming[]`. Note also that `AbsoluteTiming[FirstCase[matrix, 0, "Non zero", 2];]` is faster than without the `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Given your statement:

> I know I'll only have positive integers.

the answer I gave for [How do I check if any element in a list is positive?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8650/121) applies:

```
Positive @ Max @ d2                     (* negate with Not as needed *)
```

Early exit behaviors are also discussed in that answer.  In the case of a matrix a block-based approach naturally presents itself: test each row separately and exit if a positive value is found:

```
AllTrue[d2, Not @* Positive @* Max]
```

In the case of an all-zero array this will be significantly slower than the first form but it can exit after only one row.