# Selecting a list from a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review

In working through *Programming Paradigms Via Mathematica (A First Course)* I have come across this two part question:

> A permutation of length "n" is a list of the first n positive integers
>   in some order.  Example:  {6,1,5,3,4,2} is a permutation of length 6. 
>   A permutation is called balanced if the sum of each consecutive pair
>   is equal to the sum of the consecutive pair furthest away from the
>   original pair, if we imagine the permutation written in a circle.  For
>   instance, (6,1) and (3,4) are pairs furthest away in the example
>   above, because they are both 1 unit away from the original pair. 
>   Similarly, (2,6) and (5,3) are furthest apart.  Our example is
>   balanced because pairs furthest apart have the same sum: 6+1=3+4; 1+5
>   =4+2; 5+3=2+6; 3+4=6+1; 4+2=1+5; 2+6=5+3.  Another way to see this is to write the consecutive sums in order (7,6,8,7,6,8) and notice that
>   the corresponding sums are the furthest apart.  Note that all of this
>   makes sense only if the length of the permutation (n) is even.
>
> (a) Write a function "balancedQ[ ]" which takes one argument which is
>   a list of even length and returns True if it is balanced, False
>   otherwise.

My answer is:

```
Clear[balancedQ];

balancedQ[list_List] := Module[{list2, list3, list4, list5},
   d = 1;
   If [EvenQ[Length[list]], 
    list2 := 
     Append[Partition[list, 2, 1], {First[list], Last[list]}], {d = 2,
      Goto[End]}];
   addPairs[{m_, n_}] := m + n;
   list3 := addPairs /@ list2;
   list4 := First[Partition[list3, Length[list3]/2]];
   list5 := Last[Partition[list3, Length[list3]/2]];
   While[Length[list4] > 0, 
    If[First[list4] == First[list5], {list4 = Rest[list4], 
      list5 = Rest[list5]}, {d = 2, Goto[End]}]];
   Label[End];
   If[d == 1, Print["True"], Print["False"]]];
```

While I am sure that it can be improved upon, it does work returning true for  `balancedQ[{6,1,5,3,4,2}]` and false for  `balancedQ[{6,1,5,3,4}]` (odd # of elements) and  `balancedQ[{6,1,5,3,2,4}]` (unbalanced). The second part of the question is where I have trouble:

> (b) The Mathematica function "Permutations[]" returns all possible
>   permutations of the elements of a list.  Use "Permutations[]" and your
>   function "balancedQ[]" to find all balanced permutations of the
>   numbers {1,2,3,4,5,6}.

In looking through the previous lessons as well as the documentation center it seems to me that `Select` is the correct command, and I used it as follows:

```
Select[Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}], balancedQ]
```

To my chagrin what I got in return was a column of 720 Falses (mainly) and Trues (a few).
Therefore my question is, should I be looking at a different command, or is there an option that I am not seeing relative to `Select`?

Comment: In general you should not `Print` output, but instead return expressions.  Replace `If[d == 1, Print["True"], Print["False"]]` with `d === 1` and everything will work.  If you want the rest of your code reviewed, please add the `code-review` tag.  If not I shall close this question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thank you very much. That worked and I will read over the documentation of `===`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I would like to see some other ways of coding `balancedQ`, so I will do as you suggested and add `code-review`

Comment: Here's a possible alternative: 
`balancedQ[lst_] := If[EvenQ[Length[lst]], Length[Union[Total /@ Partition[lst, 2]]] == 1,False]`

Comment: @Jonie, I got some error messages and an incorrect answer when I ran that code with `balancedQ[{6,1,5,3,4,2}]`

Comment: odd, its running fine on mine. Did you use my old one which I removed (I left a lstBal in there in the previous version while testing). Might be the double equal sign, automatically converting to single equal sign actually.
try 
`balancedQ[lst_] := If[EvenQ[Length[lst]],  Equal[Length[Union[Total /@ Partition[lst, 2]]], 1], False]`

Comment: @Jonie, new one did clear up the error messages but `balancedQ[{6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2}]` still gives an output of "False"

Comment: 6 + 1 = 7, 5 + 3 = 8, 4 + 2 = 6. That's not balanced right?

Comment: 6+1=7; 1+5 =6; 5+3=8; 3+4=7; 4+2=6; 2+6=8 the arrangement of sums, {7,6,8,7,6,8}, is what makes this particular permutation of {1,2,3,4,5,6} balanced. I have to think of the numbers as being arranged in a circle.

Comment: ah I fully misinterpreted the question. My bad.

Comment: @Jonie, Not a problem, thanks for your time, hope that you have a good one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary issue is that you were printing the result of the test function rather than returning the expression `True` or `False` as required by other functions such as `Select`.  Instead of:

```
If[d == 1, Print["True"], Print["False"]]
```

you could write simply `d === 1`.  `===` is the short form of [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SameQ.html).  I used it rather than Equal because it will always return either `True` or `False`, whereas `Equal` may return unevaluated, e.g. `Plus == 5`.  If your code is working it should not matter, but I consider this good practice.

Other issues I note:

1. You did not add `addPairs` or `d` to the `Module` declaration.  You can see this by looking at the syntax highlighting in the Front End: the other (localized) symbols are green.
2. The construct `{d = 2, Goto[End]}` is rather unnecessary.  You could use `Return[False]` in its place.  The `Goto` construct may still have value if you have more complicated termination procedures.
3. Several definitions are made with `SetDelayed`, e.g. `list3 := ...`.  This will cause reevaluation of the code whenever this definition is referenced, slowing your program.
4. The lines `list4 := ...` and `list5 := ...` have wasteful redundancy.  You would do better to write `{list4, list5} = Partition[list3, Length[list3]/2]` which is a simple form of [destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8399/121).
5. Your `While` construct could be handled more concisely without explicit iteration.  Consider: `Inner[Equal, list4, list5, And]`.  `Inner` is a good choice because it [allows short-circuiting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/919/121).
6. The use of `Append` following [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) could be eliminated by using the advanced settings of `Partition`:  `Partition[list, 2, 1, 1]`
7. In fact both `Partition` and `addPairs` can be replaced with a single operation:
   `ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, list, 1]`
8. If desired one can streamline certain parts by not using symbols (variables) but passing arguments to an anonymous [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html).  This makes code more compact but without descriptive symbol names also harder to read.  If you follow this practice I recommend supplementing with `(* comments *)`.
9. It can be both clearer and computationally faster to move certain tests into a separate definition line; I would do that with the test for lists of odd length.

Incorporating these ideas we get something like this:

```
balancedQ2[list_List] /; OddQ @ Length @ list := False

balancedQ2[list_List] :=
  Inner[Equal, ##, And] & @@
    Partition[#, Length[#]/2] & @
      ListCorrelate[{1, 1}, list, 1]
```

I wish to stress that this is your own algorithm boiled down by the observations above.  I did not read the problem description in writing this.  There may be a more efficient way to approach the problem but I wanted to demonstrate the pure process of refactoring as I believe these elements will be more applicable to your own coding than an entirely new approach.

---

After reading the problem description a couple of additional simplifications came to mind.  First, we can replace the `ListCorrelate` operation with `list + RotateLeft[list]`, and second, while my use of `Inner` is analogous to your `While` loop and I believe valuable to understand, in this particular case you could simply use `Equal @@` to directly compare the two partitions.

```
balancedQ3[list_List] /; OddQ @ Length @ list := False

balancedQ3[list_List] :=
  Equal @@ Partition[list + RotateLeft[list], Length[list]/2]
```

Comment: OK, I made those changes and the code now runs as it should, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Clif You're welcome.  I'll continue to add recommendations as I notice things.

Comment: Ok, I have tested 1 - 4 and the code works. I'll wait to see your code regarding 5-7

Comment: @Clif Okay, I'm done. :-)

Comment: I tested the code and it works exactly as it should. I will observe the suggestion that I have seen you and others give about waiting to accept, however I do want to thank you and say that these are excellent suggestions, some of which will keep me busy looking up info (a good thing).