# Optimizing my code to generate symmetric tensors

Tags: functional-style, code-review, code-generation

I have written code that does carries out the following **task**:

Construct a fully symmetric rank-$P$ "tensor" out of a collection of user-input rank-1 vectors, and a rank-2 symmetric tensor $h$.  The number of times each vector is to be repeated, and the indices of the final rank-$P$ tensor are user-input.

**Example #1:** *Three vectors, three indices*-- 
Given input vectors $u$ repeated once, $v$ repeated twice, and indices {$a,b,c$}, the output should be the symmetric tensor:

$$u_a v_b v_c + u_b v_a v_c + u_c v_a v_b$$

**Example #2:** *Two vectors, four indices*-- 
This time, take input vector $u$ repeated twice, but with four indices {$a,b,c,d$}. Since there are two excess indices, they must be assigned to $h$.  The output:

$$u_a u_b h_{c d}+u_a u_c h_{b d}+u_a u_d h_{b c}+u_b u_c h_{a d}+u_b u_d h_{a c}+u_c u_d h_{a b}$$

**Note**: User must input such that number of excess indices must be *even*, and can never be less than the number of rank-1 tensors.

My code here as follows, starting with definitions and input:

```
(*Tells engine that \[DoubleStruckH] is symmetric *)
Clear[\[DoubleStruckH]];
Subscript[\[DoubleStruckH], i_, j_] ^:= Subscript[\[DoubleStruckH], j, i] /; ! OrderedQ[{i, j}];
```

Here are the input variables:

```
(*Example 1*)
sym = {u, v};  (*symbols of rank-1 vectors*)
n = {1, 2};    (*repetition: u once, v twice*)
indices = {a, b, c};   (*Indices of rank-3 tensor.*)

(*Example 2*)
sym = {u};     (*symbols of rank-1 vectors*)
n = {2};       (*repetition: u twice*)
indices = {a, b, c, d};   (*Indices of rank-4 tensor.*)
```

Useful definitions:

```
P = Length[indices];  (*rank of final tensor*)
r = (P - Total[n])/2; (*number of \[DoubleStruckH] in tensor*)
```

So now my clumsy code:
strategy is to begin with one-representative term of the symmetric tensor (which needs some help).

```
representative = Apply[Function[#, 
Product[1/
   n[[j]]! Product[Subscript[
    sym[[j]], #[[i]]], {i, 1 + Sum[n[[k]], {k, 1, j - 1}], 
     Sum[n[[k]], {k, 1, j}]}], {j, 1, Length[sym]}]*1/(r! 2^r)
  Product[
  Subscript[\[DoubleStruckH], #[[i]], #[[i + 1]]], {i, 
   Total[n] + 1, P, 2}]] &, {Table[Unique[], {P}]}]
```

In the case of `(*Example 1*)`, the output of `representative` is:
[image: Output of <code>representative</code>]

I know I need help here, since `representative` is supposed to be a pure function, with the arguments being the slots where the indices go.  But the output of this reveals that it doesn't fully evaluate the products.

Anyway, carrying on.  Now all I need is to add up all possible permutations:

```
answer = Plus @@ With[{func = representative}, Map[Apply[func, #] &, Permutations[indices]]]
```

[image]

It works, but it slow for large ($P\gtrsim 6$) tensors.

The two places where I need help is:

1. I need to make this work somewhat quickly for large tensors (with 6 or 8 indices).  Clearly the code does more work than it needs to because of the factorials that I use in `representative` to divide out extra terms.
2. My `representative` function needs help, too (see above).

Comment: I see that you updated your post (fixing that infinite recursion) but you haven't commented on my answer.  Does it do what you want?

Comment: Yes actually, your answer works wonderfully.  I should have commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going to try to understand everything you wrote, and I shall not attempt a full breakdown of your code as I have done for other questions tagged [code-review](/questions/tagged/code-review), unless specifically requested, as it seems to me you have a working solution with a simple flaw: you are not evaluating the body of the `Function` that you are generating.  To that end you could write:

```
representative =
 Function @@ {#, 
     Product[1/n[[j]]! Product[
         Subscript[sym[[j]], #[[i]]], {i, 1 + Sum[n[[k]], {k, 1, j - 1}], 
          Sum[n[[k]], {k, 1, j}]}], {j, 1, Length[sym]}]*1/(r! 2^r) Product[
       Subscript[\[DoubleStruckH], #[[i]], #[[i + 1]]], {i, Total[n] + 1, P, 2}]} &[
  Table[Unique[], {P}]]
```

> ```
> Function[{$1, $2, $3}, 1/2 Subscript[u, $1] Subscript[v, $2] Subscript[v, $3]]
> ```

I would apply it with:

```
representative @@@ Permutations[indices] // Tr
```

> $u_c v_a v_b+u_b v_a v_c+u_a v_b v_c$

Please let me know if this addresses your concerns.

Comment: This is fantastic!  Thank you for fixing my code, and making it go faster.  Many thanks!

Comment: @QuantumDot You're welcome.  Since this is working for you now shall I stop here, or do you need a full breakdown of every possible coding improvement I can see, as I did here: [(30195)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30195/121), [(31587)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31587/121)

Comment: No that will not be necessary.  But thanks for offering!