# Is there an equivalent of Sum for And?

Tags: boolean-computation

Is there an equivalent to `Sum` for `And`?

That is, just like instead of `Plus@@Table[f[i], {i,3,6}]` (or `Total@Table[f[i], {i,3,6}]`) you can write `Sum[f[i], {i,3,6}]`, is there a single pre-defined function that can replace `And@@Table[f[i], {i,3,6}]`?

If not, is there a better alternative for `And@@Table[...]`?

Note that, at least in Mathematica 8, `Conjunction` is not the right tool (despite the claim in the documentation that "`Conjunction` is to `And` what `Product` is to `Times`") because it only substitutes logical values, that is, it can only replace the special case `And@@Table[f[var], {var, {False, True}}]` (and of course multi-variable versions of the same structure).

Comment: I don't think so.  Are you looking for short circuiting?  `SetAttributes[and, HoldAll];
and[expr_, iter_] := And @@ Catch[Table[With[{e = expr}, If[e === False, Throw[False]]; e], iter]]`

Comment: You could also use `Product` together with `Boole`.

Comment: Short-circuiting would certainly be nice. The following also works, but seems quite unelegant: `Module[{},Do[If[!f[i],Return[False,Module]],{i,3,7}];True]`.

Comment: In version 10, the function `AllTrue` will do this [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AllTrue.html). It even short-cuts.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/916/are-there-all-and-any-functions-in-mathematica "Are there “All” and “Any” functions in Mathematica?"

Comment: @DanielW it is time they added these functions ! they can be very useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you should be happy to use `Array`:

```
Array[x, 10, 0, And]
```

> ```
> x[0] && x[1] && x[2] && x[3] && x[4] && x[5] && x[6] && x[7] && x[8] && x[9]
> ```

It works on V9, don't know if for previous versions too.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that `Array` can take a head. Actually I *did* look for the possibility to use your own head for `Table` and it doesn't have that option (or I just wasn't able to figure it out), but I didn't think of looking at `Array`. It also works with version 8.0.

Comment: @celtschk I wasn't sure what is the solution but I had an impression that I've seen one. And finally I've found it :) I think it will be useful for me too, so thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

A first pass at a true equivalent to `And` and `Table`, except with early exit (short circuit) behavior:

```
SetAttributes[and, HoldAll]

and[body_, iter__] := Module[{all = True},
   Do[If[all = all && body, , Break[]], iter];
   all
 ]

and[Positive[i], {i, 7}]
and[Positive[i], {i, {foo, 0, 1, 2, 3}}]
and[Positive[i], {i, {foo, 1, 2, 3, bar}}]
```

> ```
> True
>
> False
>
> Positive[foo] && Positive[bar]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Combining ideas already expressed in the comments:

```
SetAttributes[and, HoldAll]

and[body_, iter__] := (Do[If[! body, Return[False, CompoundExpression]], iter]; True)
```

Now:

```
and[PrimeQ[i], {i, {2, 3, 5, 7}}]

and[PrimeQ[i], {i, {2, 3, 4, 5}}]
```

> ```
> True
>
> False
> ```

This is not actually equivalent to `And` and `Table`, e.g. here:

```
And[True, foo, bar, True]
```

> ```
> foo && bar
> ```

Comment: Nice. It's too easy to forget that `;` also is a "function" (i.e. has its own head, `CompoundExpression`) in Mathematica, which of course can be used in `Return`. Certainly more elegant than my "dummy module".