# Selecting sublists of different length if at least one element of the sublist fulfills a criterion

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have the following list, containing sublists with 1,2 or 3 elements.

```
 list= {{10.7}, {10.5}, {9.83},{7.64}, {4.76}, {4.21, 
      5.64}, {3.75}, {3.4, 5.11}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5},{7, 5, 3}}
```

I have to select sublists if at least one element of the sublist is between 5 and 8.
I think it should work with Select[], but I can't figure it out, because the sublists have different lengths.

Comment: Related: [(916)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/916/121), [(8650)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8650/121).  Possibly useful: [(9719)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9719/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = {{10.7}, {10.5}, {9.83}, {7.64}, {4.76}, {4.21, 5.64}, {3.75},
        {3.4, 5.11}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5}, {7, 5, 3}};
Select[list, Or @@ (5 <= # <= 8 & /@ #) &]
(* {{7.64}, {4.21, 5.64}, {3.4, 5.11}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5}, {7, 5, 3}} *)
```

You get the same result using siblings of `Select`:

```
Pick[list, Or @@ (5 <= # <= 8 & /@ #) & /@ list]
Cases[list, _?(Or @@ (5 <= # <= 8 & /@ #) &)]
```

Answer (score 7):

In *Mathematica* 10 you can use [`AnyTrue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnyTrue.html) for this:

```
 list ~Select~ AnyTrue[5 <= # <= 8 &]
```

> ```
> {{7.64}, {4.21, 5.64}, {3.4, 5.11}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5}, {7, 5, 3}}
> ```

You can also use [`VectorQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorQ.html) and [`Not`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Not.html):

```
Select[list, ! VectorQ[#, 5 > # || # > 8 &] &]
```

> ```
> {{7.64}, {4.21, 5.64}, {3.4, 5.11}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5}, {7, 5, 3}}
> ```

If aiming for speed consider purely numeric operations.  Assuming all positive numbers as in your example you could use:

```
Pick[list, UnitStep[Max /@ Clip[list, {5, 8}, {-1, -1}]], 1]
```

> ```
> {{7.64}, {4.21, 5.64}, {3.4, 5.11}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5}, {7, 5, 3}}
> ```

Timings:

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 200}, {50000, 50}];

Select[list, AnyTrue[5 <= # <= 8 &]]                         // Timing // First
Select[list, ! VectorQ[#, 5 > # || # > 8 &] &]               // Timing // First
Pick[list, UnitStep[Max /@ Clip[list, {5, 8}, {-1, -1}]], 1] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.8736
>
> 1.5288
>
> 0.0156
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Some variations along with timings:

```
list = {{10.7}, {10.5}, {9.83}, {7.64}, {4.76}, {4.21, 
   5.64}, {3.75}, {3.4, 5.11}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5}, {7, 5, 3}};
```

---

The result for the list in the OP is the same for the different variations.

> {{7.64}, {4.21, 5.64}, {3.4, 5.11}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5}, {7, 5, 3}}

---

**TIMINGS**

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 200}, {50000, 50}]; (* Mr. Wizard's test list *)
```

**Using `Between`:**

```
Select[AnyTrue[Between[{5, 8}]]][list] // Timing // First
```

> 3.40082

**Using `IntervalMemberQ`:**

```
Pick[list, 
 IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{5, 8}], #] & /@ list // Map[Apply[Or]]
 ] // Timing // First
```

> 1.49761

**Using `MemberQ` with `Pick`:**

```
Pick[list, MemberQ[#, _?(5 <= # <= 8 &)] & /@ list] // Timing // First
```

> 1.34161

**Using `MemberQ` with `Select`:**

```
Select[list, MemberQ[#, _?(5 <= # <= 8 &)] &] // Timing // First
```

> 1.29481

---

Mr. Wizards's last solution outperforms others by a factor of `80+` whenever sublists must be selected for containing any element within a continuous interval.

Answer (score 2):

Using another variant of `Cases` works, too:

```
Cases[list, {a___, x_, b___} /; 4 < x <= 5 -> {a, x, b}]
(* {{4.76}, {4.21, 5.64}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5}, {7, 5, 3}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{10.7}, {10.5}, {9.83}, {7.64}, {4.76}, {4.21, 5.64}, 
  {3.75}, {3.4, 5.11}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5}, {7, 5, 3}};

f[a_][b_] /; Or @@ Map[Between[#, a] &] @ b := b
f[_][_] := Nothing

f[{5, 8}] /@ list
```

{{7.64}, {4.21, 5.64}, {3.4, 5.11}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5}, {7, 5, 3}}

```
f[{7, 8}] /@ list
```

{{7.64}, {7, 5, 3}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Extract` and `Position`:

```
list = {{10.7}, {10.5}, {9.83}, {7.64}, {4.76}, {4.21, 5.64},
        {3.75}, {3.4, 5.11}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5}, {7, 5, 3}};

Extract[#, Position[#, {a___, x_, b___} /; 5 <= x <= 8]] &@list

(*{{7.64}, {4.21, 5.64}, {3.4, 5.11}, {3.13, 4.76, 6.5}, {7, 5, 3}}*)
```