# Selecting all the elements of different length that contain only numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, symbols

If I have a list of lists with different lengths:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {x}, {1, x}, {2}, {2, 3}}
```

How can I extract all the sub-lists with no symbols:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {2}, {2, 3}}
```

There must be an easy way to do this but I can't find it. Unfortunately, I'm not so good with Mathematica to be able to modify similar cases that I found(for example [Link1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77681/selecting-sublists-of-different-length-if-at-least-one-element-of-the-sublist-fu) and [Link2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16694/numericq-equivalent-for-lists)) to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {x}, {1, x}, {2}, {2, 3}}, {__?NumericQ}]
```

Comment: Or 3 underscores if empty lists should also be kept.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Or `DeleteCases[
 {{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {x}, {1, x}, {2}, {2, 
   3}}, {___, _Symbol, ___}]`

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to use `VectorQ`:

```
lis = {{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {x}, {1, x}, {2}, {2, 3}};
Select[lis, VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &]

(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {2}, {2, 3}} *)
```

Variations:

```
Select[lis, AllTrue[#, NumericQ] &]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think @march's answer is probably the best way. Here's another for giggles...

```
Select[{{1, 2, 3}, {1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {x}, {1, x}, {2}, {2, 3}}, ! MemberQ[#, _Symbol] &]
```

Comment: Interesting. What is the name of that `_Symbol` part? I want to search for other properties that have the same usage.

Comment: @BehzadNazari That's shortcut for `Blank[Symbol]` which is a pattern match for a certain `Head`. `Head[x]` (if `x` isn't defined) evaluates to `Symbol`. Try `Head /@ {x, 1.0, 1, "test"}` for examples.